# Electron, contextIsolation and contextBridge

Tags: javascript, security, electron

I recently had to revamp an old Electron app. I found out that it had `contextIsolation` set to `false`, so I went ahead and set it to `true` (and btw set `nodeIntegration` to `false`).

As expected, it broke the ipc communications

So I used, as advised in many places, a preload script that enables some communications channels

Here is my `preload.js`:

```js
const {
    contextBridge,
    ipcRenderer
} = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            console.log("Send on channel " + channel)
            // whitelist channels
            let validChannels = [];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            console.log("Receive on channel " + channel)
            let validChannels = [
                "set-auth-token",
                "set-window-name",
                "get-window-name",
                "send-message-to-one-drive",
                "update-badge",
                "is-hidden",
                "open-google-sign-in"
            ];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
            }
        }
    }
);
```

My issue is the "api" parameter, I don't know what to put in there.

Knowing that the website that's loaded by that app sends messages this way:

```js
let electron = false;
if ('require' in window) {
  electron = window.require('electron');
}

const isAppDesktop = !!electron;

const DesktopHelper = {
  isAppDesktop() {
    return isAppDesktop;
  },

  updateBadge(badgeCount) {
    return isAppDesktop ? electron.ipcRenderer.send('update-badge', badgeCount) : undefined;
  },

  setAuthToken(token) {
    return electron.ipcRenderer.send('set-auth-token', token);
  },

  isHidden() {
    return isAppDesktop ? electron.ipcRenderer.sendSync('is-hidden') : undefined;
  },
};

export default DesktopHelper;
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(apiKey, api)` - the `apiKey` argument is the name of the object that will be exposed as `window[apiKey]`.

In your example, the `apiKey` is set to the string `"api"`, so the exposed methods are available in the `window.api` object. You can access them as `window.api.send` and `window.api.receive`.

The methods in `DesktopHelper` should look like this:

```js
  updateBadge(badgeCount) {
    return isAppDesktop ? window.api.send('update-badge', badgeCount) : 
      undefined;
  },
```

Or simply `api.send('update-badge', badgeCount)`, since window is the global. You may obviously want to pick a more descriptive name for the API.